# AWS Lmabda function does not connect to Elastic Cache

Tags: amazon-web-services, memcached, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, amazon-elasticache

This is my Lambda function.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import elasticache_auto_discovery
from pymemcache.client.hash import HashClient

import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    AWS_ELASTIC_CACHE_ENDPOINT = 'name.jag4mt.cfg.aps1.cache.amazonaws.com:11211'
    print ('Start discovery')
    nodes = elasticache_auto_discovery.discover(AWS_ELASTIC_CACHE_ENDPOINT)
    print ('Discovery complete')
```

Once this function is invoked, I don't see results beyond `Start discovery`. This function is hosted in the same VPC as the Elastic Cache (`memcached` is the engine). The security group currently allows for traffic on port 11211 from the CIDR block of the VPC group.

The Lambda function has been assigned a role to which the policies for VPC execution and Elastic Cache full access has been assigned.

Can you please tell me what I need to look to fix this issue?

Comment: What do the logs show? Does the function timeout? Is there any error message? Also, the Lambda function does not need the "ElastiCache Full Access" IAM role in order to connect (it doesn't need any special IAM permissions for that). It would only need that role if it was creating or deleting ElastiCache clusters.

Comment: Yes. The function times out. It shows the first `print` and then times out.

Comment: I had to add an outgoing rule in security group for port 11211. Have it working now.

Comment: That's a bit surprising because security groups are stateful. If you allowed inbound rule for port 11211 then it should work for outbound as well. You mean security group or NACL?